# Trying to set element state from SharedPreferences, but only the default value is applied

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

OK so I'm trying to make a settings activity, and that's not going well. Right now it only has one setting which is displayed as a Spinner.

I'm  successfully saving the selected item to SharedPreferences, but I can't figure out how to make the activity apply the saved data to the View on start.
I am trying to apply whatever int is paired with the key "spinnerPosition" to `Spinner.setSelection();`, but the default value in `sharedPreferences.getInt(String key, int defValue);` overrides it.

Here is the file sharedPreferences saves to:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
    <map>
    <string>com.example.SettingsActivity$1@277a0f70</string>
    <string name="finalWeighType">Pounds</string>
    <int name="spinnerPosition" value="1" />
    </map>`

And some Logcat:

`04-04 18:21:13.849: D/spinner Listener(9027): ok
    04-04 18:21:15.035: D/onPause(9027): Saving Settings
    04-04 18:21:15.035: I/System.out(9027): iSavedPos: 9
    04-04 18:21:19.030: W/InputEventReceiver(9027): Attempted to finish an input     event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
    04-04 18:21:19.036: I/System.out(9027): iSavedPos 9
    04-04 18:21:19.037: D/Do(9027): running
    04-04 18:21:19.037: D/pos def(9027): ok
    04-04 18:21:19.404: D/spinner Listener(9027): ok`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private Spinner selectWeighType;
SharedPreferences weighTypeLoader;
String finalWeighType;
public static final String DEFAULT = "UNSET";
public int itemSelectedPosition;
SharedPreferences getItemSavedPosition;
private int itemSavedPosition;
private boolean populated = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    // add items to selectWeighType Spinner
    populateSelectWeighType();
    // add listener to selectWeightType Spinner
    selectWeighTypeListener();
    weighTypeLoader = getSharedPreferences("weightType", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Load saved data.. hopefully
    getItemSavedPosition = getSharedPreferences("weightType", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    itemSavedPosition = getItemSavedPosition.getInt("spinnerPosition", 9);
    System.out.println("iSavedPos " + itemSavedPosition);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    do {Log.d("Do", "running");
        switch (itemSavedPosition) {
            case 0:
                selectWeighType.setSelection(0);
                Log.d("pos 0", "ok");
                break;
            case 1:
                selectWeighType.setSelection(1);
                Log.d("pos 1", "ok");
                break;
            case 2:
                selectWeighType.setSelection(2);
                Log.d("pos 2", "ok");
                break;
            default:
                selectWeighType.setSelection(1);
                Log.d("pos def", "ok");
        }
        populated = true;
    }while(populated == false);
}

public void populateSelectWeighType(){
    selectWeighType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weight_type_spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> selectWeighTypeAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.weight_type_select,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    selectWeighTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    selectWeighType.setAdapter(selectWeighTypeAdapter);

}
public void selectWeighTypeListener(){
    selectWeighType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weight_type_spinner);

    selectWeighType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String weighTypeSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            itemSelectedPosition = position;
            int rowID = (int) id;
            Log.d("spinner Listener", "ok");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Toast weightTypeToast;

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences commitWeighSetting = getSharedPreferences("WeightType", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editSetting = commitWeighSetting.edit();
    editSetting.putString("WeighType",
            selectWeighType.getSelectedItem().toString());
    editSetting.putInt("spinnerPosition", itemSelectedPosition);
    editSetting.commit();
    Log.d("onPause", "Saving Settings");
    System.out.println("iSavedPos: " + itemSavedPosition);

}

}
```

Layout xml

```
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.SettingsActivity"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weight_type_setting_title"
    android:text="@string/weight_type_setting_title"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weight_type_spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/weight_type_spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weight_type_setting_title"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weight_type_setting_title"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"

    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read `spinnerPosition` value from `SharedPreferences` instance with name `spinnerPosition`, while saving `spinnerPosition` value for `SharedPreferences` with name `WeightType`. You should either read the `spinnerPosition` value from `SharedPreferences` instance with name `WeightType` or save it to the `SharedPreferences` instance with name `spinnerPosition`.

Comment: Oh that's certainly a problem. Thanks for opening my eyes. I wish I could report that it solved the problem, but at least I might be much closer to figuring it out.